# Group by muliple rows text in one row in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to merge the rows in one row bases the unique column in my case offer_num, I want all the notes of this offer to be in one row itself need your help in the same in python pandas

[image]

Comment: I need the last column data to be combined in one row bases the offer_num